# value doesn't get updated in the template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Hi,
I have fName, lName, and position set to empty string and I want their value to be changed after clicking the button and to save that value to the this.templates ${this.fName} etc.

the showMessage method should receive the click and update the values and inject a template. Everything is fine apart of updating the values. When it gets to the "mP.innerHTML = _this.template;" line the values are empty just as set at the start.

Weird thing is that the console.log(_this.fName) that runs before "mP.innerHTML = _this.template;" gives out a correct value on click.

What could be the problem? How do I solve this?

```js
class Message {
  constructor() {
    this.fName = '';
    this.lName = '';
    this.position = '';

    this.bride = {
      fName: 'Anna',
      lName: 'Doe',
      position: 'bride'
    };

    this.groom = {
      fName: 'John',
      lName: 'Doe',
      position: 'groom'
    };

    this.template = /*html*/`
    <div class="message message-show">
        <div class="message-close">x</div>
        <h1>
          My name is ${this.fName} ${this.lName}, ${this.position}
        </h1>
    </div>`;

    this.elements = function() {
      let messageButtons  = document.querySelectorAll('.wed-couple-newlyweds-message');
      let messagePopup    = document.querySelector('.message-popup');
      let messageClose    = document.querySelector('.message-close');
      let messageDiv      = document.querySelector('.message');
      return {
        messageButtons: messageButtons,
        messagePopup: messagePopup,
        messageClose: messageClose,
        messageDiv: messageDiv
      };
    };


    //Initiate Methods

    //End of Methods.
  }

  //declare methods
  // 1. show message on click.
  showMessage() {
    var _this = this;
    let els = new this.elements();
    let mB = els.messageButtons;
    let mP = els.messagePopup;
    let mD = els.messageDiv;
    mB.forEach(function(message) {
      message.onclick = function() {
      if (message.classList.contains(`wed-couple-newlyweds-message-bride`)) {
        console.log('bride')
        _this.fName = _this.bride.fName
        _this.lName = _this.bride.lName
        _this.position = _this.bride.position
        console.log(_this.fName)
        mP.innerHTML = _this.template;
      } else {
        console.log('groom')
        _this.fName = _this.groom.fName
        _this.lName = _this.groom.lName
        _this.position = _this.groom.position
        console.log(_this.fName)
        mP.innerHTML = _this.template;

      }
      let mC = els.messageClose;
      _this.closeMessage();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template literal like

```
var foo = `Hello, ${name}`;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var foo = "Hello, " + name;
```

---

It takes the values of variables at the time it is interpreted and produces a regular string.

It does not create any kind of string-like object which dynamically updates its value by watching the values of the variables that were interpolated.

---

If you want to get a new string, using the new values of the variables, then you need to rerun the code.

Make it into a function.

Comment: This response would be more helpful if you could provide an example of how to change the var returned output to a string. Currently when I change the template string to a function return value it throws an error.